# Retrieving adjaceny values in a nng igraph object in R

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

**edited to improve the quality of the question as a result of the (wholly appropriate) spanking received by Spacedman!**

I have a k-nearest neighbors object (an igraph)  which I created as such, by using the file I have uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rcwahdl4qcgy30l/AACTBm4be30F9_QSK1xAT3zja):

I performed the following operations on the data, in order to create an adjacency matrix of distances between observations:

```
W <- read.csv("/path/sim_matrix.csv")
W <- W[, -c(1,3)]
W <- scale(W)

sim_matrix <- dist(W, method = "euclidean", upper=TRUE)
sim_matrix  <- as.matrix(sim_matrix)

mygraph <- nng(sim_matrix, k=10)
```

This give me a nice list of vertices and their ten closest neighbors, a small sample follows:

```
  1 ->  25  26  28  30  32 144 146 151 177 183     2 ->   4   8  32  33 145 146 154 156 186 199
  3 ->   1  25  28  51  54 106 144 151 177 234     4 ->   7   8  89  95  97 158 160 170 186 204
  5 ->   9  11  17  19  21 112 119 138 145 158     6 ->  10  12  14  18  20  22 147 148 157 194
  7 ->   4  13 123 132 135 142 160 170 173 174     8 ->   4   7  89  90  95  97 158 160 186 204
```

So far so good.

What I'm struggling with, however, is how to to get access to the values for the weights between the vertices that I can do meaningful calculations on.  Shouldn't be so hard, this is a common thing to want from graphs, no?

Looking at the documentation, I tried:

```
degree(mygraph)
```

which gives me the sum of the weights for each node.  But I don't want the sum, I want the raw data, so I can do my own calculations.

I tried

```
get.data.frame(mygraph,"E")[1:10,]
```

but this has none of the distances between nodes:

```
   from  to
1     1  25
2     1  26
3     1  28
4     1  30
5     1  32
6     1 144
7     1 146
8     1 151
9     1 177
10    1 183
```

I have attempted to get values for the weights between vertices *out* of the graph object, that I can work with, but no luck.

If anyone has any ideas on how to go about approaching this, I'd be grateful.  Thanks.

Comment: What's the nng function? Your question isn't reproducible as is.

Comment: Please make a toy example with a small distance matrix that we can all run. Give all the code. My answer isn't what you wanted, because you weren't clear. I think you probably just have to look up `sim_matrix[i,j]` for each of `from, to` to read off the distance, if `sim_matrix` is an NxN distance matrix.... otherwise if its an Nxm data matrix then lookup the data and do pythagoras.

Comment: @Spacedman: I updated the question and included a link to the adjacency matrix I am using (in a csv form).

Comment: Now show us the code that reads the CSV in and creates `sim_matrix`. Just plain `read.csv` gets me a 252x253 matrix of.. what? Distances? With an extra column at the start. Ok, I need to clean that out... Why am I doing this? You should just paste the two or three lines that YOU'VE already worked out so we don't have to.

Comment: Is the file, which you've not told us anything about, a matrix of DISTANCES, or a matrix of VARIABLES where the distance is computed between rows? The fact that it is square makes me think the former, but that means you should use `dx=sim_matrix` in your `nng` call. This has a massive bearing on how to get the eventual distances, since in the former its just a lookup and in the latter it involves pythagoras (or manhattan, or mahalanobis) distances.

Comment: Spacedman:  the question has been edited appropriately.  I'm aware that I'm coming of like one of those people who diminish the value of SO by writing incomplete questions and I apologize.

Comment: Close! I can't match that adjacency list you print out as "a small sample". So I've just wasted ten minutes trying to figure out if that's my fault or yours. I think its yours! `get.adjlist(mygraph)[[1]]` is ever so slightly different, so you've either given us different data or made a typo. I know its a small thing but precision is so important here. Also I think its clear now that `sim_matrix` is a distance matrix so you **have** to do `dx=sim_matrix` or `x=W` otherwise your graph is the wrong thing to start with. Get code working with tiny hand-provable examples first.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you are starting with a dataset, or with a distance matrix, e.g. `nng(x=mydata,...)` or `nng(dx=mydistancematrix,...)`, so here are solutions with both.

```
library(cccd)

df <- mtcars[,c("mpg","hp")]    # extract from mtcars dataset
# knn using dataset only
g  <- nng(x=as.matrix(df),k=5)  # for each car, 5 other most similar mpg and hp
V(g)$name <- rownames(df)       # meaningful names for the vertices
dm <- as.matrix(dist(df))       # full distance matrix
E(g)$weight <- apply(get.edges(g,1:ecount(g)),1,function(x)dm[x[1],x[2]])

# knn using distance matrix (assumes you have dm already)
h <- nng(dx=dm,k=5)
V(h)$name <- rownames(df)
E(h)$weight <- apply(get.edges(h,1:ecount(h)),1,function(x)dm[x[1],x[2]])

# same result either way
identical(get.data.frame(g),get.data.frame(h))
# [1] TRUE
```

So these approaches identify the distances from each vertex to it's five nearest neighbors, and set the edge `weight` attribute to those values. Interestingly, `plot(g)` works fine, but `plot(h)` fails. I think this might be a bug in the plot method for `cccd`.

If all you want to know is the distances from each vertex to the nearest neighbors, the code below does not require package `cccd`.

```
knn <- t(apply(dm,1,function(x)sort(x)[2:6]))
rownames(knn) <- rownames(df)
```

Here, the matrix `knn` has a row for each vertex and columns specifying the distance from that vertex to it's 5 nearest neighbors. It does not tell you which neighbors those are, though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found a `nng` function in `cccd` package. Is that it? If so.. then `mygraph` is just an `igraph` object and you can just do `E(mygraph)$whatever` to get the names of the edge attributes.

Following one of the `cccd` examples to create `G1` here, you can get a data frame of all the edges and attributes thus:

```
get.data.frame(G1,"E")[1:10,]
```

You can get/set individual edge attributes with `E(g)$whatever`:

```
> E(G1)$weight=1:250
> E(G1)$whatever=runif(250)
> get.data.frame(G1,"E")[1:10,]
   from to weight   whatever
1     1  3      1 0.11861240
2     1  7      2 0.06935047
3     1 22      3 0.32040316
4     1 29      4 0.86991432
5     1 31      5 0.47728632
```

Is that what you are after? Any `igraph` package tutorial will tell you more!